# Good introductory book on Mechanics

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics

I have to learn mechanics from a mathematical perspective for by graduate courses. I have a basic idea about Newtonian mechanics from school and under-grad mathematical background . Could some one suggest a introductory level book on mechanics

The portions needed to be covered are "D'Alembert's Principle,Lagrange's and Hamitonian methods and Motion of rigid bodies in two dimensions"

Comment: Look here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations

Comment: Thank you ! Useful link